# How to split a doted string and retrive the data from object by notation?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

At present, I do this approach:

```
var obj = {
  sender: {
    name: "tech"
  }
}


var str = "sender.name".split('.');

console.log( obj[str[0]][str[1]] ); //getting update as 'Tech'
```

In the above I use `obj[str[0]][str[1]]` for just 2 step, this is works fine. In case if I received a long node parent and child this approach not going to work.

Instead is there any correct dynamic way to do this?

Comment: `In case if I received a long node parent and child this approach not going to work` What does that mean?

Comment: In case of 100 nodes, how can I write manually? I am looking for a dynamic approach.

Comment: Like 100 different strings in the same format?

Comment: Yes, getting from Back end, need to show in front end. basically getting from 2 different server

Comment: Can you give an example of what that may look like? Would all of the strings be returned in an array? Like `["sender.name", "sender.email", "sender.other"...]` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to navigate through each key.

```js
var obj = { sender: { name: "tech" } };
var str = "sender.name".split('.').reduce((r,k) => r[k],obj);
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
var obj = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      baz: {
        sender: {
          name: "tech"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


const props = "foo.bar.baz.sender.name".split('.');
const val = props.reduce((currObj, prop) => currObj[prop], obj);
console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and reduce the path for the result. The function uses a default object for missing or not given properties.

```js
function getValue(object, path) {
    return path
        .split('.')
        .reduce(function (o, k) { return (o || {})[k]; }, object);
}

var obj = { sender: { name: "tech" } },
    str = "sender.name";
        
console.log(getValue(obj, str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be looking into libraries such as "https://lodash.com/"

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10

Use _.get : https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get

You can simply write `_.get(obj, 'sender.name', 'default')` and you will get the value as you expect